# Allure reporting: if suite name contains dot, suite name in reporting is truncated

Tags: suite, allure

If suite name contains dot, suite name in reporting is truncated.
The XML seems to have proper name as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:test-suite xmlns:ns2="urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru" start="1424101948829" stop="1424102027462" version="1.4.4">
<name>SampleSuite.xml</name>
<test-cases>
    <test-case start="1424101949080" stop="1424101952336" status="passed">
....
...
```

But html report(generated using allure.bat generate  allure-results -v 1.4.0) is truncated as below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not a bug. There happens extracting simple class name out of fully qualified one. Usually suite names look like "my.company.SimpleTest". In that case current behavior is more preferred.

Comment: Me and Karthik use custom TestNG adapter, so, might be not relevant to Allure framework.